# Issue with JNLP not loading configuration file

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, executable-jar, jnlp

So I am trying to use JAVA web start to run a project that uses calls to urls to preform parts of it's service and the urls I need are stored in a separate client.properties file. I have got the project to correctly boot from JNLP (and it works perfectly on eclipse), but it stalls out when it tries to use the urls for it's api calls so I assume that it isn't correctly reading the properties file. I have jared the properties file and included it in the jnlp as

```
<jar href="client.properties.jar"/>
```

Am I supposed to include this file in some other way? Or do I need to change how my program obtains these properties from the more normal way?

Comment: *"..but it stalls out when it tries to use the urls for it's api calls so I assume.."*  That's a dangerous thing to do (assume).  Put some `System.out.println(..)` statements in the app, to check what is actually happening.  Stack traces for catches are also handy (unless the app. has implemented logging or some other way to see error output).  Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: So I did as you said and have confirmed that it craps out as soon it tries to pull information from the config file. Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"*  More details.